# Eclipse: how to change the color of the return type in method declarations

Tags: java, eclipse

It would be nice to make the method return type stand out more from the method name by using a different color. I tried Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring and what I  want is not there. I'm wondering if it's hidden somewhere else, or if there's an extension.

Comment: I guess it is just impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I never knew about this... But I went to exactly where you pointed out and managed to change the colors in the way you described. There's an option for "Keywords excluding 'return'" (which includes the keywords before the method name like "public" and "static") and one for "Method declarations" (which is the name of the method itself, and isn't enabled by default). There's also one for "Others", which controls the return type (but also a lot of other things, so you might not want to mess with that). Anyway, you can change the colors of one or more of those to get the desired effect.

Comment: None of these does what I want though. One changes the method name's colour, the other changes keywords, and "other" changes a whole bunch of stuff. I want to change the colour of the return type.

Anyway, I ended up just changing the colour of the method declaration. It fulfills a similar purpose.